# VBA Class does not support automation or does not support expected interface

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code trying to query a ms sql database but I get the above error on the last line  any help please

```
     'Declare variables'
Dim objMyConn As ADODB.Connection
 Dim objMyRecordset As ADODB.Recordset
    Set objMyConn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set objMyRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim strSQL As String

'Open Connection'
    objMyConn.ConnectionString = "connection string"
    objMyConn.Open

'Set and Excecute SQL Command'
    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM dbtable"

'Open Recordset'
    Set objMyRecordset.ActiveConnection = objMyConn
    objMyRecordset.Open strSQL

'Copy Data to Excel'
 (ERROR HERE-->)      ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset (objMyRecordset)
```

Comment: Try removing the parentheses from around `objMyRecordset` and see if that makes any difference...

Comment: Or add 'Call ' at the start of the line